# iPhone SDK - how to add a CSS into a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, css, sdk, uiwebview

I've read many of the existing questions and answers for my problem but none seem to answer it specifically and simply.

I am displaying many HTML files in my app and want to use a CSS to help format them. The CSS file will be held locally together with the HTML files.

I think I want to add the CSS ref inline - presuming that's then right way to do it?

My code is

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[adviceContent loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                                                        pathForResource:[advice objectForKey:@"HTML"] ofType:@"html"]
                                                                           isDirectory:NO]]];
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
```

}

And I've inserted my CSS reference in the HTML file thus within the head tags <
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="photovaluesCSS_2column.css" media="screen"/>

Can someone explain where I'm going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When loading the HTML, you need to specify a base URL for the css file, so your controller will "know" where that CSS file is located.

Here's a code that loads a html string which uses a css file. You can load the entire css from a file, or modify it as you need.

```
  // HTML files are stored in the main bundle
  NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 
  NSString *path = [bundle bundlePath];

  NSString *filename = @"none";
  NSString *fullPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:filename ofType:@"html" inDirectory:path];


  // load a HTML from a file
  NSString *chapter_filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section%d", _chapter];      
        NSString *sectionHTMLPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:chapter_filename ofType:@"html"];

  NSString* htmlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:sectionHTMLPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

  // add a generic template and the css file directive
  NSString* htmlString = @"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"> <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"he\" lang=\"he\"><head><style type=\"text/css\" media=\"all\">@import \"styles.css\";</style><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" /></head><body>%@</body></html>";


  // load the html into a web view 
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
  [_webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:htmlString, htmlContent] baseURL:url];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this out today. I assume from your reply that I do not need to reference the CSS (inline) within my HTML when using your solution as you load it as "htmlstring" externally?l

Comment: Works a treat! (Don't forget to scroll across to see the key `<style type=\"text/css\" media=\"all\">@import \"styles.css\";</style>` part!)